# Golang convert map[string]*[]interface{} to slice or array of other type

Tags: go

I have the following

```
type Results map[string]*[]interface{}

var users *[]models.User
users = getUsers(...)

results := Results{}
results["users"] = users
```

Later, id like to be able to grab `users` from this map and cast it to `*[]models.User`

I am having a hard time figuring out the right way to do this. Id like to do the following, but it obviously does not work.

```
var userResults *[]models.User
userResults = (*results["users").(*[]models.User)
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Your Result type is "unidiomatic" (an euphemism for "dead ugly"). Don't do such things. Redesign, refactor.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some comments on your code besides the conversion (which is also addressed at the end).

- There is no real need of using a pointer to a slice in this case, since slices are just header values pointing to the underlying array. So slice values would work as references to the underlying array.
- Since an `interface{}` variable can reference values of any kind (including slices), there is no need to use a slice of `interface{}` in `Result`, you can just define it as `type Results map[string]interface{}`.

Having said this, here's how the modified code would look like:

```
var users []User
users = getUsers()

results := Results{}
results["users"] = users

fmt.Println(results)

var userResults []User
userResults = results["users"].([]User)

fmt.Println(userResults)
```

You can find the complete code in this playground:

https://play.golang.org/p/zL4IkWy97j